# Stream Analytics - Blob output filename?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

For Blob storage output, how do we control filename? I tried the Path pattern but it only creates the virtual folder in blob. Cannot define the filename in the output.

Example in the path pattern I specified "test" which results in - /blobcontainer/**test**/1513855769_670e84ee67f643d7aff3cad3cc6d9333.csv

Also in the path pattern I specified "test/filename.csv" - which results in - /blobcontainer/test/**filename.csv**/1513855769_670e84ee67f643d7aff3cad3cc6d9333.csv

Comment: There are no folders in containers, on any cloud provider (Amazon, Azure, Rackspace etc). Containers are flat, otherwise they wouldn't scale - folders require recursive processing to identify/access their contents. It's only a *convention* used by applications that treats `/` as a folder indicator.  What you typed *is* the file name's *prefix*. This probably explains why you can control the rest of the name too - each job needs to be able to identify its own files so it doesn't have to perform expensive existence or lock checks. ASA has to scale to million events/sec

Comment: Only blob prefix is customizable, not the actual blob name. Blob names will be in {Number}_{guid}.{extension} format.  Do you have any specific scenario for which you would like the blob names to be customizable as well?

Comment: @VigneshChandramohan possible scenario: stream analytics job stores an output to blob named "latest.json". From the application side it is easy to fetch that blob. Now the only option is to read the whole container and find the latest one by timestamp.

Comment: @Zygimantas instead of listing the whole container, can you list with a prefix? For example, you can list with /blobcontainer/test/filename.csv/ as prefix and it will only list blobs under that path.